Should we use SSL on our website?
Should an Exchange about Cryptography utilize SSL encryption on it's website?
I'm not quite sure what the cost is, or how these are given out on the Exchange, but it seems pretty silly not to provide users with the basic protections provided by SSL:

Verification of Origin
URI Obfuscation

Nobody other than the client and server know which page is actually being requested.

Proper usage

Be a shining example on how to correctly use SSL/HTTPS.



What are the benefits of SSL on a site like this? All the content is publically available anyways. Login credentials (not username/password as that page is protected, but say a session cookie, etc) might be one thing, but I'm not even sure if that is necessary (I don't know all the specifics of OpenID).

I've edited my question to show a few examples of reasons SSL use might be useful here.

See Why doesn't security.stackexchange.com use HTTPS? on [security.se] and Why doesn't the Stack Overflow team fix the Firesheep style cookie theft? on the main meta.

While I agree with your suggestion in general, I'd like to note that the URI obfuscation point is probably mostly a red herring; HTTPS leaks the request and response lengths, which should make it fairly easy for an attacker to determine with reasonable accuracy which pages are being accessed. For an example of such attacks, see e.g. Chen et al. 2010, "Side-Channel Leaks in Web Applications: a Reality Today, a Challenge Tomorrow".

Yes, we should. 
Unfortunately StackExchange is an USA based company. With the extremely weak consumer protection and privacy laws in the USA, StackExchange does not consider the exposure of email addresses and ip-addresses (moderator tools) and account highjacking an issue. 
Please see Why doesn't the Stack Overflow team fix the Firesheep style cookie theft? for an official statement on this issue.
SSL is not as expensive anymore than it used to be in the past. Yes, it still creates a bit of overhead, but given the privacy implication, I consider that negligible.
